# Allowing POSTs to static files in a CouchDB CouchApp

Tags: facebook, couchdb, couchapp

When serving static assets from a CouchApp (e.g. HTML and JS for a Backbone.js app), a 405 Method Not Allowed error is appropriately kicked when those static pages are POSTed to. However, when developing a Facebook app for canvas/iframe, Facebook sends all requests as POSTs. Is there any way to make Couch allow the POST method?

Comment: Wait, even if you *could* POST to a static document attachment, what would you expect to be the result anyway, in an ideal world? You can definitely receive POST to a _show function; I wonder if there is a possible workaround but I'd like to hear your details more.

Comment: obviously it logically doesn't make any sense, but FB requires POSTing to the Canvas page (which in a CouchApp is a static page since there's no server-side processing)...

Answer (score 0):

I am pessimistic about this. I'm not sure but it may not be possible.

Is it possible to tell Facebook to add custom headers? Couch supports an `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header in POST requests. Just set it to the HTTP method you really wanted.

Comment: Not possible to tell Facebook to add custom headers. I'm thinking I may have to put a proxy between FB and Couch, which unfortunately eliminates all those CouchApp benefits.

Comment: Bummer. I have some more questions I'll add to the question section.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and so far I was able to avoid another hoster by simply letting CouchDB output javascript that redirects my request (so basically the client's browser).

As @JasonSmith commented, _show functions are able to receive POST methods; so I've basically created a new _show function called shows/proxy.js which (in it's most basic functionality) only includes this:

```
function(doc, req) {
   return "<script>document.location='TARGETURL';</script>";    
}
```

Replace TARGETURL with your real Canvas URL page.
Then I setup the FB Canvas URL to point to this page,

```
http://fbdemo.iriscouch.com/fbdemo/_design/fbdemo/_show/proxy?
```

This works just fine in the FB Canvas, and finally shows my CouchApp! Next step is to start passing QueryString parameters from FB (depending on login, graph, etc...), but I'll leave that as an exercise to our readers ;-)

Hope this helps!